# Not able to test subscription availability on App Store's sandbox environment

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

While testing the purchase of renewable subscriptions on App Store's sandbox environment we have observed that defining subscription availability (either restricting to specific countries or making it unavailable) has no effect.

No matter what is the purchasing Sandbox Tester's assigned region or even if the product was marked as unavailable - always **every product defined** in App Store Connect is returned when fetched using StoreKit 2 API ([Product.products(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/3851116-products)).

Due to the described behaviour we are not able to test different sets of products being available for specific regions.

**Note:** The testing was done on app that is not yet published and the products as well were not reviewed - they all have "*Ready to Submit*" status. The app was built from Xcode (TestFlight distribution was not used).

--

**Question 1:** Is that an expected behaviour?

**Question 2:** When testing TestFlight distributed app will the availability be respected?

**Question 3:** Is the subscription's status in App Store Connect ("*Ready to Submit*") related to how it behaves? Is the behaviour varying when testing on Sandbox or using TestFlight?

Comment: Hello, Spanish Inquisition, I have the same problem. I created a new subscription and set availability to a specific set of countries (12 countries) but when I'm testing it with an account from another country, it's still available.

Do you have any updates? Does it finally work properly on production?

Comment: I too am experiencing this issue, has there been any update at all?